# Sending a websocket message for each line of rsync output using mojolicious (a perl web framework)

Tags: perl, websocket, rsync, mojolicious

I want to show the progress of an rsync copy on a website. I've got the the stdout of rsync being read with a while loop using \r as the line break so as I can get updated progress as it comes (since rsync separates each update with a \r so as to write it on the same line).

I want to send it to the browser via web sockets however the problem I've been having is that mojo won't send the text till after the while loop is complete (thus defeating the perps of getting updates on the progress).

The closet solution I can find online is [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mojolicious/m6OHryCL3Hg/lib8qR5iThsJ).
But I don't know how many lines there'll and I'm not sure how I would automate recursion anyway.

Here's what I have so far:

```
websocket '/rsync' => sub { 

    my $self = shift; 
    # Incoming message 
    $self->on(message => sub { 
            my ($self, $msg) = @_; 
        $self->send("echo: $msg"); 
    }); 
    { 
        open(RSYNC, "-|", "rsync -av --progress --stats '/dir1' /dir2"); 
        local $/ = "\r"; 
        while(<RSYNC>) { 
            $self->send($_); 
        } 
    } 
};
```

Edit: Changed "r" to "\r"

Comment: Well, that Sebastian Riedel guy in that link, who says it could not be done, is probably the same Sebastian Riedel who created mojolicous in the first place. So i would guess, unless thinks have changed since that post, his solution is probably the best.

Comment: It may be irrelevant, but your sample code shows $/ = "r" instead of $/ = "\r"

Comment: @DeVadder Possibly but that post is nearly three years old. If that truly is the only solution then I guess there's no way to do what I want then since I don't think you can generalise his solution for n parts :(

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Yeah, it was "\r" but I copied and pasted the code into a blank nopaste.info and that for some strange reason converted it to "r". Sorry about that.

Comment: I take it just replacing the `\r` with `\n` before sending does not help either, right?

Comment: @DeVadder No, it's \n by default anyway. With \n a line equals a whole file (eg one huge concadinated string with each progress update upto %100). Where as \r causes a line to equal each progress update.

Comment: @Callum Gare: I know, i meant if after you have read the input using `\r` as input delimeter, replace that `\r` at the end of the line with `\n` before sending. Maybe that causes mojo to flush? No idea, though. And you would probably have to translate the `\n` back to `\r` at the target.

Comment: @DeVadder Ah, I get you. Sadly no cigar.

Comment: @CallumGare First (pseudo-code): local $/ = undef; my $output = <RSYNC>; print STDERR Dumper($output); -- find out what rsync is actually giving you.